# asp:listview add a <div class="clear"> after every 3 items

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

How would i go about (*preferably not in the code behind*) adding a clear in ever third item. This is the code in question...

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvproducts" runat="server" DataSourceID="entyproducts">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <div class="s_item grid_3"> <a class="s_thumb" href="product.html"><img  
   src="images/product_180x180.jpg" title="Samsung SyncMaster 941BW" alt="Samsung 
    SyncMaster 941BW" /></a>
      <h3><a href="products.aspx"><%# Eval("title") %>  </a></h3>
      <p class="s_model"><%# Eval("model") %>  </p>
       $ <%# Eval("salesprice") %>  
      <p class="s_rating s_rating_5"><span style="width: 60%;" class="s_percent">   
      </span></p>
      <a class="s_button_add_to_cart" href="product.html"><span class="s_icon_16"><span   
       class="s_icon"></span>Add to Cart</span></a>
    </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

In the original markup the designer has that `<div class="clear"></div>` after every third item in the list. How do I do that (*preferably not in the code behind*)? Is their a template I can put that in (*I think there should be*)?

Comment: @SliverNinja agreed. jQuery is made this situation :)

Comment: oops :x jQuery is made FOR this situation :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvproducts" runat="server" DataSourceID="entyproducts">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="s_item grid_3">
                <a class="s_thumb" href="product.html">
                    <img src="images/product_180x180.jpg" title="Samsung SyncMaster 941BW" alt="Samsung  
SyncMaster 941BW" /></a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="products.aspx">
                        <%# Eval("title") %>
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <p class="s_model">
                    <%# Eval("model") %>
                </p>
                $
                <%# Eval("salesprice") %>
                <p class="s_rating s_rating_5">
                    <span style="width: 60%;" class="s_percent"></span>
                </p>
                <a class="s_button_add_to_cart" href="product.html"><span class="s_icon_16"><span
                    class="s_icon"></span>Add to Cart</span></a>
            </div>
            <%# (Container.DataItemIndex != 0 && (Container.DataItemIndex+1) % 3 == 0) ? @"<div class='clear'></div>" : string.Empty %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: i tried that but did not work  'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem' does not contain a definition for 'ItemIndex' and no extension method 'ItemIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive o

Comment: If ItemIndex does not work for you, try with Container.DataItemIndex

Comment: it not working as should its producing strange results its doing the first one after row three as should but second one after row 2

Comment: @DavidBuckley: (Container.DataItemIndex+1)%3 == 0 should work as the Index starts with 0(zero).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is your friend :)

Put this at the top of you your page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         $("a.s_button_add_to_cart").append("<div class="clear"></div>");}
</script>
```

More on how to select exactly what you are looking for: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

If you aren't using it today you are missing out on a truly powerful library :) Everyone else is using it.. so why aren't you? :P PEEEER PRESSURE! :D

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/